# Quotient of the polynomial ring over a local noetherian ring is finitely generated?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, local-rings

I am going through these lecture [notes](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2021fa/LectureNotes10.pdf), and I am confused about the proof of Corollary 10.10 there.

> **Corollary 10.10.** Let $A$ be a local noetherian domain with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, let $g \in A[x]$, and let $B := A[x]/g(x)$. Every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $B$ contains the prime $\mathfrak{p}B$.

In the proof of this, the author writes

> The ring $B$ is finitely generated over the noetherian ring $A$, hence a noetherian $A$-module, ...

I don't understand this part, because I think if $g$ is not monic, then $B$ will not be finitely generated? For example, take $A = \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}$, and $g(x) = 3 \in A[x]$. Then $B := A[x]/g(x) = \mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[x]/3\mathbb{Z}_{(3)}[x] = (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[x]$ which is certainly not finitely generated over $A$? I'm not sure what I am missing here. If there is another source for the proof of this corollary, please let me know. Thank you so much.

Comment: You cannot use g=3=0 for the quotient. If g is not zero, because you are in a filed, you can assume that g is monic.

Comment: @Bongo Local ring Z_(3) does have unique maxinal ideal 3Z_(3), though. (Edit) I also do not get what this material is trying to convey..

Comment: My hunch is that `deg g > 0` is implied.

Comment: This happens when one learns mathematics from lecture notes instead of books.

Comment: @user26857 I tried to learn from Cassels and Frohlich but found it to be too dry for self-studying. Would you recommend me some books that cover similar material as these notes?